# Meteor/Mongo accessing object attribute

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this code:

```
Template.keskmine.events({
  "submit .arvutaKeskmine": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    numberSelect = Numbers.find({}).fetch();
    numberCount = Numbers.find({}).count();
    console.log(numberSelect)
    console.log(numberCount)
  }
})
```

which returns me:

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object_id: "vrTKRc2GtDQfRa5Ex"number: "3131"__proto__: Object1: Object2: Object3: Objectlength: 4__proto__: Array[0]
average.js:36 4
```

but I want to do something like this:

```
Template.keskmine.events({
  "submit .arvutaKeskmine": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    numberSelect = Numbers.find({}).fetch();
    numberCount = Numbers.find({}).count();
    console.log(numberSelect.number)
    console.log(numberCount)
  }
})
```

for this numberSelect.number I get `undefined`

I want to be able to get each numberSelect.number value and then calculate the sum of them.

How can I push each instance of numberSelect.number into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Using the popular `lodash` library you can use the `sum` method as shown below. [(docs)](https://lodash.com/docs#sum)

```
Template.keskmine.events({
  "submit .arvutaKeskmine": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    numberSelect = Numbers.find({}).fetch();
    numberCount = Numbers.find({}).count();
    console.log(_.sum(numberSelect, function (number) {
        return number.number
    }));
    console.log(numberCount)
  }
})
```

add the `lodash` library with `meteor add erasaur:meteor-lodash` if you haven't already to use this answer.